# How do I save a virtual interface?

Tags: networking, virtualization, qemu, network-bridge

Say I create a virtual bridge interface and configure it as follows:

```
ip link add type bridge name br1
ip link addr add 10.10.10.1/24 dev br1
```

How do I make it so that this configuration persists across reboots? I tried putting it in `/interfaces`, but it doesn't work. It seems to me it has to either be a physical interface or to have some physical interface associated wit hit, otherwise it won't be brought up and even saved.

I've been reading a lot of threads, but it just doesn't work, as I said above.

I'm simply setting up this bridge for a VM. Qemu is really buggy on my machine and I had to jump through hoops to get it working, but long story short, I just create this bridge (that's all there is to it), then configure the guest OS, and then I have everything connected as I want.
Problem is - how do I make it so that this little br1 thing is saved and restored/brought up on boot?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much. Sharing my solution for others who might stumble on the same issue:

You add the interface to the interfaces file, as usual. Continuing with the example above:

```
auto br1
iface br1 inet static
address 10.10.10.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.10.10.0
broadcast 10.10.10.255
```

So far so good, but this won't work by itself. This is the configuration of the device, but the device won't have been created on bootup.
The key is to use the pre-up command. From the manpage:

```
pre-up command
   Run command before bringing the interface up.  If this command fails
   then  ifup  aborts, refraining  from marking the interface as configured,
   prints an error message, and exits with status 0.
   This behavior may change in the future.
```

So you can use this hook to execute the `ip link` commands you'd normally execute at runtime.

```
pre-up ip link add dev br1 type bridge
```